# HTML 5 Placeholder: when user selects field make text disappear

Tags: css, forms, html, input, placeholder

Is this possible to achieve without javascript/jQuery?

I currently have a login template with the input fields as:

```
 <input id="username" type="text" name"username" placeholder="username" autofocus>
```

I was wondering if there was a way when the user clicked their mouse on the field to type the placeholder text would disappear without using javascript if possible? Before this i was just using value and echoing the variables out into the fields but currently experimenting with HTML 5 and CSS3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New browsers have a native way to do this. And if supported, you don't have to do anything.

With older browsers you do need to use javascript.

Edit: When using new features on old browsers its called Pollyfills. Here is a [nice list with a lot of pollyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) that can be used together with [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/), that in turn can detect this features.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into more depth about browser compatibilities using this method.